# Obtain virtual column formula with SQL

Tags: oracle, query, virtual-columns

We want to update the condition of a virtual column and to minimize error posibilites we want to extract the exact function working today to add new parameters to take into account.

I've firstly test with `desc tablename` but doesn't work, only shows column types.

Answer (score 2):

This information can be found in the `DATA_DEFAULT` column of [[DBA|ALL|USER]_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/DBA_TAB_COLUMNS.html#GUID-91F945AE-5778-45A6-A07E-775A006A9AA1).

Example:

```
SQL>  create table t1(c1 number, c2 number generated always as (abs(ceil(c1)*2)) virtual);

Table created.

SQL> select column_name, data_default from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'T1';

COLUMN_NAM DATA_DEFAULT
---------- --------------------
C1
C2         ABS(CEIL("C1")*2)
```